# What is the purpose of using 'Static' in this Flutter/Dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, static

My code do not work without 'Static'. What does it do? and why the code don't work without it?
Is it simillar or related to initState() Function?

Did a reasearch but Google answers weren't enough. Thanks.

```
class ResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ResultScreen({super.key});

  static int correctAnswersCount = 0;

  static int correctAnswersCounter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
      if (selectedAnswers[i] == questions[i].answers[0]) {
        correctAnswersCount++;
      }
    }
    return correctAnswersCount;
  }

  static int x = correctAnswersCounter();
  int y = questions.length;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        ResultText('You have answerd $x of $y questions currectly.')
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Static' keyword is used to indicate that variable is belongs to a class instead of instance of a class.

You are getting error because you are trying to access instance variable `selectedAnswers` and `questions` from Static method. Dart doesn't know which class they belong to.

you can pass them like this if you don't want static

```
class ResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 ResultScreen({super.key});

 static int correctAnswersCounter(List<String> questions, List<String> selectedAnswers) {
   int correctAnswersCount = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < selectedAnswers.length; i++) {
     if (selectedAnswers[i] == questions[i].answers[0]) {
       correctAnswersCount++;
     }
   }
   return correctAnswersCount;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   int x = correctAnswersCounter(questions, selectedAnswers);
   int y = questions.length;
   return Center(
     child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
       ResultText('You have answered $x of $y questions correctly.')
     ]),
   );
 }
}
```

this might help you https://www.darttutorial.org/dart-tutorial/dart-static/